# In R is it possible to use MAE (Mean Absolute Error) instead of RMSE as the cost function to a linear regression (lm/glm)

Tags: r, glm, lm

I am trying to do several regressions on financial data, and one problem with financial data is that it tends to have lots of extreme outliers that are possibly not all that informational.  In R linear regression uses RMSE as it's cost function.  I understand this, RMSE is more useful for regression in that it has a derivative etc.  But it also tends to penalise outliers more heavily than MAE which treats all values as equal.  So I was wondering is there any parameter that can be passed to lm/glm that will instruct it to use MAE instead of RMSE as the cost function?  I can think of a few alternative work-arounds, weighting by the inverse of the absolute return or applying a transformation, but it would be nicer if I could just do a regression using MAE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Searching for `R robust linear regression` lead me to the `rlm` function from the `MASS` package (included standarly in R). I think this is a nice place to start for your solution. It does not work with the MAE, but I would read up on how `rlm` performs robust fitting (i.e. fitting while not being unduly influenced by outliers).

Comment: As somewhat of a beginner the help text for rlm went way over my head.

Comment: "Psi functions are supplied for the Huber, Hampel and Tukey bisquare proposals as psi.huber, psi.hampel and psi.bisquare. Huber's corresponds to a convex optimization problem and gives a unique solution (up to collinearity). The other two will have multiple local minima, and a good starting point is desirable."

Comment: Selecting method = "MM" selects a specific set of options which ensures that the estimator has a high breakdown point. The initial set of coefficients and the final scale are selected by an S-estimator with k0 = 1.548; this gives (for n >> p) breakdown point 0.5. The final estimator is an M-estimator with Tukey's biweight and fixed scale that will inherit this breakdown point provided c > k0; this is true for the default value of c that corresponds to 95% relative efficiency at the normal. Case weights are not supported for method = "MM"."

Comment: That said, I just tried a comparison of rlm vs lm with a fairly easy prediction.  lm performed quite badly, having a correlation of 0.78 on the test set, whereas rlm had a correlation of 0.92.  I played around with a few other algorithms in caret and they all overfitted and performed worse than lm. So although I don't really understand what rlm is doing, it does seem pretty robust and is doing what it does well.

Comment: @user3762838 I would have a look at the MASS book, it contains the details of `rlm`. In general, having a look at the wiki page of `Robust linear regression` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_regression) is a good point to start.

Comment: consider quantile regression (`quantreg` package) [will write this up if I get the chance]